# When can you choose to italicize part of a quote? If you do so, what words must you add and where must you add them?

Tags: italics

I thought you only italicize a  title of a book, music etc.. I'm not honestly sure about  If you do so, what words must you add and where must you add them?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. The presentation of a quotation is largely a matter of style; the way to indicate editorial modifications to it will similarly vary. You should adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, observe the guidance of your preferred [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579).

Answer (score 1):

You can italicize a part of a quote to draw emphasis, and indicate that the italics were added and not part of the original quote in brackets.

> "I cannot say *with certainty* that it wasn't me. [emphasis added]"

Different style guides differ on exactly what words to use and where to put them, but the MLA style guide offers a good example:

> Emphasis may be added to a word or phrase in a quotation by placing it in italics.
>   When this is done the note [emphasis added] or [italics added] must be inserted in brackets at the end of
>   the quotation (within the quotation marks), or if the emphasis comes at the end of the sentence, in
>   parentheses outside the quotation marks.

https://debate.uvm.edu/dcpdf/mlacrib.pdf