# Italicizing a word within a quoted sentence

Tags: punctuation

When quoting someone, is it allowable to bring attention to a particular word by italicizing it if it wasn't originally italicized by the author?

I have two quotes from different people on the same topic in one paper. They both use a word I want to bring attention to. One is "selves" and the other is "personae".

I am bringing attention to these words to tie something together. Can I italicize a word in a quoted sentence?

Comment: The usual practise is to mention that the emphasis is yours after the quote but it's a matter of style rather than language.

Comment: https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/punctuation/when/when-to-italicize.html#targetText=By%20YourDictionary,as%20say%2C%20bold%20or%20underline.

Comment: Somewhat related - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384392/when-can-you-choose-to-italicize-part-of-a-quote-if-you-do-so-what-words-must. It provides an answer to your question, though.

Comment: After the quoted material, just add ***[italics mine]***.

Comment: It's only fair to point out _any_ modifications made to an original, as differences in tone etc can be (or why bother making them!) significant.

Comment: "I cannot say *with certainty* that it wasn't me. **[emphasis added]**"

Comment: @KillingTime It's a matter of not misatributing. Nothing to do wih style, really.